# Show dashed line of mean for each bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I would like to plot a dashed line that shows the average of value for both variables. This is my code for the bars plot:

```
 import matplotlib
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np

 men_means = [2000, 3400, 3000, 3005, 2700]
 women_means = [2500, 3200, 3004, 2000, 2005]

 x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
 width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
 rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')
```

This is the image of what I'm expecting as a result:
[image: age]

Comment: Do you want your line to be dashed instead of fully connected? The line from your picture does cross the average of each bar.

Comment: @CeliusStingher A dashed line, I tried `plot.axhline(np.mean(df), linestyle='--',  color='blue')` but this is for all bar plot. Can you help me, thansk!!!

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking

Comment: I'll edit your question so it's properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

There's no Matplotlib magic involved here; you just need to properly define what you want to plot.

The lines you want to draw are connections between the center of the bars.
The center of a bar is computed by offsetting `x` by `width +/- 2`, and by dividing `y` by 2.

You can plot those two lines with a simple `plt.plot`:

```
# Your code

plt.plot(
    x - width/2, 
    [y / 2 for y in men_means], 
    linestyle="--", 
    linewidth=3, 
    color="black"
)
plt.plot(
    x + width/2, 
    [y / 2 for y in women_means], 
    linestyle="--", 
    linewidth=3, 
    color="purple"
)
```

Output:

[image]